# how to yield an anonymous class in IEnumerable.GroupBy<T> "on the fly" (without enumerating result) in C# LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I do like this now (thanks to StackOverflow):

```
IEnumerable<object> Get()
{
     var groups = _myDatas.GroupBy(
       data => new { Type = data.GetType(), Id = data.ClassId, Value = data.Value },
       (key, rows) => new 
       {
           ClassId = key.Id,
           TypeOfObject = key.Type,
           Value = key.Value,
           Count = rows.Count()
       }));

       foreach (var item in groups)
       {
           yield return item;
       }
}

IEnumerable<MyData> _myDatas;
```

But is possible to make faster or more "elegant" by not having last foreach loop, but yielding it when the group/anonymous class instance is created?

I would guess fastest way would be to write it open and:

1. sort the _myDatas
2. enumerate it and when group changes yield the last group

But I'm trying to learn some LINQ (and C# features in general) so I don't want to do that.

The rest of example is here:

```
public abstract class MyData
{
    public int ClassId;
    public string Value;
    //...
}

public class MyAction : MyData
{
    //...
}

public class MyObservation : MyData
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return `groups` directly, though you might need to change your return type from `IEnumerable<Object>` to just `IEnumerable`.

So:

```
IEnumerable Get()
{
    var groups = _myDatas.GroupBy(
        // Key selector
        data => new {
            Type = data.GetType(),
            Id = data.ClassId,
            Value = data.Value
        },
        // Element projector
        (key, rows) => new 
        {
           ClassId = key.Id,
           TypeOfObject = key.Type,
           Value = key.Value,
           Count = rows.Count()
        }
    );

    return groups;
}
```

`groups` has the type `IEnumerable< IGrouping< TKey = Anonymous1, TElement = Anonymous2 > >`, so you can return it directly.

Comment: And if he didn't want to change the return time he could return groups.Cast<object>();

Comment: Hmm. It seems that I have understood very little about yielding and returning IEnumerable<T>. I have to read the facts when, why and how the enumeration is done when  this method is used as "source" in foreach loop (like foreach(var item in example.Get()) assuming the code in question was in object example) . Maybe my question was not sensible at all. Thanks!

Comment: Ur answer (w Tom's addition) was a good point but I tried to ask a different question. Each "round" in a calling method foreach loop is executed the "iterator" method is executed from where it was left last time until a yield statement. I was trying to yield a group whenever it was ready like in my description how to do it fastest (sort and yield latest group when group changes). So I did understand how yielding and IEnumerable<T> works but maybe what I wanted is not possible. Also maybe badly asked question.